# scala : no common ancestor available for asInstanceOf[]

Tags: scala, class, inheritance

I created some case classes used as messages in akka.
When the program receives some messages, it calls the method `asInstanceOf[]`, but I don't know what to put inside the brackets, as the message can be one of the 3 differents case classes.

here is a try :

```
abstract class Retour
case class Naissance(val sender : ActorRef) extends Retour
case class NaissanceEtMort(val sender : ActorRef) extends Retour
case class PlusUnMoisOK(val sender : ActorRef) extends Retour
```

but at the execution of my program I get this error message:

```
lapins.Clapier$PlusUnMoisOK$ cannot be cast to lapins.Clapier$Retour
```

can you help me?

EDIT:

the line of the error is those with [Retour] in :

```
val future = ask(couple,PlusUnMois)
val result = Await.result(future,timeout.duration).asInstanceOf[Retour]
```

and the error is below:

```
[ERROR] [07/02/2015 01:33:48.436] [clapier-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://clapier/user/$a] lapins.Clapier$PlusUnMoisOK$ cannot be cast to lapins.Clapier$Retour
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: exception during creation
```

EDIT2:

resolved! the message sending was incorrectly written : indeed, I wrote "sender ! PlusUnMoisOK" instead of "sender ! PlusUnMoisOK(self)"

Comment: Can you should the code of the line that fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With:

```
ask(couple,PlusUnMois)
```

You are sending the class `PlusUnMois` as a message. If you are doing the same in your `couple` actor `Await.result` is returning the class `PlusUnMois` not an object of `PlusUnMois`. Trying to cast the class `PlusUnMois` to `Retour` results to an error. Try sending an instance of `PlusUnMois`, like:

```
val future = ask(couple,new PlusUnMois(someActorRef))
```

The same should be done in your `couple` actor:

```
sender ! new PlusUnMois(someOtherActorRef)
```

Moreover, instead of using `asInstanceOf` consider using pattern matching:

```
 Await.result(future,timeout.duration) match {
   case m : Naissance => // do something Naissance
   case m : NaissanceEtMort => // do something NaissanceEtMort
   case m : PlusUnMoisOK => // do something PlusUnMoisOK
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could pattern match on the result of the future. Something like:

```
Await.result(future, timeout.duration) match {
  case n: Naissance => // ...
  case nm: NaissanceEtMort => // ...
  case pm: PlusUnMoisOK => // ...
}
```